# Окончание, местоимение, артикль

Tags: этимология

Можно ли утверждать, что некогда все окончания слов в русском языке являлись местоимениями, выступая при этом также и в роли артикля (краткое прилагательное обозначало неопределённый объект, а полное — определённый)?

Comment: Окончания в русском языке являлись местоимениями? Окончания чего? Почему вопрос вызывает вопрос?

Comment: Окончания любого слова. Например, красного, окончание "ого" от местоимения его + чередование согласных е->о (ёзеро -> озеро); красному, окончание "ому" от местоимения "ему" + чередование согласных е->о; рус. тот (ст.слав. тои) окончание "и" от краткого местоимения "и" (нь), см. иже; ту окончание "у" от краткого йотированного (под ударением) местоимения "ю" (ню), см. юже. Как-то так

Comment: Откуда вы берете эти вопросы?

Comment: вернее окончание любого имени (прилагательного, существительного)